# ¿ Como llegar a una parte de otra carpeta de mi web?

Tags: html, css, webservice, servidor

Hola He creado una web y los botones de la barra de navegación me llevan pagina abajo, hasta las partes con el ID establecido de esta manera:
`<li><a href="#service">Servicios</a></li>`
Tengo un formulario en otra carpeta (form) desde el cual llamo a la sección "servicios" de la siguiente manera:
`<li><a href = "../index.html #service"> </a> </li>`
Pues cuando lo tengo en mi ordenador en local, desde la carpeta del formulario me lleva a la sección `#service` de la pagina principal.
El problema viene cuando lo subo al servidor y pincho en "servicios" desde el formulario, me da error:
La URL solicitada form/index.html no se encontró en este servidor.
¿ Como puedo solucionar, si me funciona en local y no en el servidor?
Gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías verificar que todos tus archivos se encuentran subidos al servidor y confirmar esto? Incluye también tu página y formularios en la pregunta, para entender mejor el problema.

Comment: @JYass si que esta todo subido, pues funciona todo menos cuando llamo a la sección "servicios" desde el formulario. Pues si llamo a la pagina completa funciona, lo único cuando llamo a esa sección no funciona.                                 Gracias.

Comment: Estás accediendo desde ip? prueba juegando con la ruta relativa asi: ***<li><a href = "../../index.html#service"> </a> </li>*** y quitando el espacio del ***index.html*** al ***#service***.

Comment: Gracias @BrunoEchevarríaQuiroga funciona perfectamente, si lo pones como respuesta la daré por buena, por si sirviera a alguien

Comment: Vale! Ahora lo actualizo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes tener cuidado si estás accediendo desde una ip o desde el dominio.
Puedes probar jugando con la ruta relativa de la siguiente manera:

```
<li><a href = "../../index.html#service"> </a> </li>
```

También debes quitar el espacio del index.html y #service.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias lo hice así y funciono.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a que te refieres con lo de "una ip", @Bruno Echevarría Quiroga

Comment: Me refiero a si accedes a tu web desde http://192.120.3.219/index.html o desde http://midominio.com/index.html